# Java. Best way to split each element of List

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I optimize this using streams ?

```
    List<String> prepared = new ArrayList<>();
    availableFieldsFromImage.forEach(field -> {
        if(field.contains(".")){
            prepared.add(field.split("\\.")[0]);
        } else {
            prepared.add(field);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`split` returns the initial string if the delimiter is not found, so there is no need to test for "." before performing the split:

```java
List<String> prepared = availableFieldsFromImage.stream()
                        .map(field -> field.split("\\.")[0])
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
List<String> prepared = availableFieldsFromImage.stream()
        .map(field -> field.contains(".") ? field.split("\\.")[0] : field)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
    List<String> prepared=availableFieldsFromImage.stream()
.map(i->i.contains(".") ? i.split("\\.")[0] : i)
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `map` and then `collect`

```java
availableFieldsFromImage.stream().map(field -> field.contains(".") 
                                        ? field.split("\\.")[0] 
                                        : field)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```